# Woocommerce - display excerpt on product loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I need a little help getting the product's short description to be displayed in the product loop (archive). I've added the following code to the theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'output_product_excerpt', 20 ); 
    function output_product_excerpt() { 
    global $post; 
    echo '<div class="my-excerpt">'.wp_trim_words($post->post_excerpt,10).'</div>';
}
```

It works fine, but it's applied to all the products. What can I add to make it work just for a category only?

Comment: Could you clarify what it is that you are trying to achieve: are you trying to display the excerpt on only a specific category of products?

Comment: @Frits Exactly. Using that code it works for all products, but I want it displayed only for a certain category.

Comment: I’ve added a potential solution for you, have a look and let me know if it works for you! :)

Comment: @Frits Thank you! It works, I've added the cat id and the excerpt shows only on this category. However, there's an issue with this. On the front page I have a couple of sections where I display a few products from some categories. On the products from that particular category, the excerpt now shows up twice. I'm guessing the component that I'm using to display the products (Woo Product Category in Visual Composer) is already configured to show the short description, that's why it shows it twice now.

Comment: Not a problem - have edited my answer to include the `is_shop()` conditional (4th line from the bottom). That way, it will only echo this on the "shop / archive page" :) Let me know if that solves it for you :)

Comment: @Frits Hi there. I found a small issue with that condition. While the code works fine IF I'm in the shop page, it doesn't work if I'm on that category page. Basically there's the shop menu where I have all the categories, including that one that I needed to have its products excerpts displayed. If I go to that category OR any other that includes these products, the code does not work. Maybe the condition can be reversed? Like display the short description everywhere BUT the front page?

Comment: Yeah that’s not too hard, you would just replace is_shop() with !is_front_page() :)

Comment: @Frits Once again, you're amazing, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to get the product categories of the product by using get_terms, throwing those into an array and checking if the array contains your specific category.

It would essentially look like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'output_product_excerpt', 20 ); 
function output_product_excerpt() { 
    global $post; 

    //get the individual products' categories and put them in an array
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $product_categories[] = $term->term_id;
    };

    //check if the array contains your specific $category_id that you are targeting
    if ( is_shop() && in_array( $category_id, $product_categories )) {
        echo '<div class="my-excerpt">'.wp_trim_words($post->post_excerpt,10).'</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the code from bbloomer for adding the excerpt to woocommerce product archive in child theme function.php and somewhere else the lengt in in signs.
But it owerrode the general excerpt lenght so i added conditions according this tutorial
https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/
and my first not clean but working not fully control C code is :), hope it helps:

```
// product excerpt in the archive
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'bbloomer_ins_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35, 2 );

function bbloomer_ins_woocommerce_product_excerpt() {
the_excerpt();
                }
// add custom classes for different excerpts types
add_filter ('get_the_excerpt','custom_filter_excerpt');

function custom_filter_excerpt ($post_excerpt) { 
    if ( is_woocommerce() ) {
    $post_excerpt = '<p class="custom-woocommerce-excerpt-shop">' . $post_excerpt . '</p>';
    
    }
     else { 
    $post_excerpt = '<p class="custom-woocommerce-excerpt-post">' . $post_excerpt . '</p>';
        }
     return $post_excerpt;
  }

// set up lenght in signs for different exerpts types
add_filter('the_excerpt','excerpt_char_limit');
function excerpt_char_limit($e){   
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); 
    if ( is_woocommerce() ) {

        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 155); // lenght in signs for shop
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
        $excerpt = $excerpt.' ...';
                                    }
     else {
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 355);
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " ")); 
        $excerpt = $excerpt.' ...';
                                    }   
return $excerpt;
                }
```